# ASP.NET CheckBoxList with multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

How do I make a `CheckBoxList` in ASP.NET which looks like this?:

[image: Desired CheckBoxList]

When a List Item is selected I would need the values from both columns. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a GridView with CheckBoxField instead

Comment: A repeater is probably more appropriate for this. It has the least amount of overhead. The other option would be to have a listview but seeing as you don't need paging etc .... a repeater would be the most appropriate choice.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: GridView works perfectly! Please post it as an answer, so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're presenting multiple columns, a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0.ASPX) control is a better alternative to CheckBoxList.

It contains a [CheckBoxField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx) column type that renders as column of checkboxes.